# How to manage concurrent LMDB writes in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, concurrency, lmdb

I know LMDB does not support concurrent writes.

I have an application where concurrent write attempts are very rare, but they may occasionally happen. How should this be managed in a Python application?

Specifically:

- does a concurrent write attempt raise an exception in the Python LMDB binding, so that it would be possible to schedule a retry in the exception handler? is trying a concurrent write even safe?
- or, is there any other or better way to handle concurrent write attempts?

Answer (score 2):

According to lmdb documentation lmdb handles the concurrent writes on its own. When multiple read_write transactions are opened at once.Except the active write transaction Lmdb makes all the other write transactions to wait until the current active write transaction commits. Thus it handles concurrent writes.

Comment: so in essence, even though our application can hit an lmdb environment with multiple concurrent write calls, lmdb internally will handle it. this handling will just grab all those concurrent requests, and put them in order. so we are wasting computation concurrentizing something that won't be even concurrently run. and all the work done on it, undone. is it??